# A question about a manifold in an $n$-dimensional Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, alexandrov-geometry

Suppose $M$ is an $n$-dimensional Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below(maybe with boundary), subspace $A\subset M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold without boundary. Then whether every point in $A$ is a manifold point in $M$?

Here, a point in $M$ is a manifold point if it has an open neighbourhood in $M$ such that it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21512/.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Thank you! I will have a look. My question is a special case there.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin It seems that the argument there works for Alexandrov spaces without boundary. But in my question, I did not assume they are boundaryless. Hence maybe my question is not a special case there. What is your opinion? Thank you for your response.

Comment: @LewisZang: If boundary is not empty, you can pass to the doubling; this should solve the problem.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin It is a very good idea! Thank you!